# How to backup an android phone with a broken screen (using linux)

Tags: broken-screen

I have dropped my android phone and the screen broke. In the meantime the battery has died. I would like to use adb to make a backup (I run Ubuntu).

```
adb devices
```

shows the device. However it is shown as unauthorized.
Can I somehow use adb to backup the phone nonetheless?

PS1: This is a Oneplus 7T on Android 12.
PS2: I have managed to connect the phone to an external display via a USB type-c hub (It shows a screensaver-like screen with the time) as suggested in a Oneplus forum. However, the keyboard and mouse signals are ignored by the phone).

Comment: adb access is impossible unless you authorize in the shown dialog on the phone. The only way to do so with a broken touch screen would be a bluetooth keyboard. But as the device ran out of power it will now require you to unlock the lock screen. Unless this is done all user data remain encrypted.

Comment: @Robert would somehow connecting an external display work?

Comment: Some phones support certain USB-C alt modes for external displays, other don't. Usually such details can not be found in hardware spec, so I would ask in a OnePlus or model specific forum. There is he biggest chance to get the information if it works at all and if yes what adapter you need. But the there is the problem that the USB port is blocked...